# QT5 qDebug()<<QByteArray empty

Tags: qt5

I try get HTML use `QNetworkAccessManager` from a URL. statusCode is 200. debug `reply->readAll()` have data length 35988. But if I use `qDebug()` it print empty.
My environment `windown7 x32` `Chinese +qt5.5 x32(mingw)`. I copy this code to `linux(qt5.5 x64)`. it's Working.

> Can print HTML content, why?

please help me.

my code is:

```
QEventLoop loop;
QTimer timer;
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzA4MjAzMzg4NA==&mid=208317469&idx=4&sn=0928285db7c368e276e85519b3d0763b&3rd=MzA3MDU4NTYzMw==&scene=6#rd"));
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36" );
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8");
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "none");
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
request.setRawHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.setRawHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
timer.start(timeout);//超时10秒
loop.exec();
if(reply->error()){
    qDebug()<<"error";
}
QByteArray res= reply->readAll();
reply->close();
reply->deleteLater();
// QString str = QString::fromUtf8(res.data(), res.size());
qDebug()<<statusCode;
qDebug()<<res;
```

Comment: Post your Question clearly. **its hard to Modify it even**

Answer (score 1):

You should connect to the `SIGNAL(finished())` of the QNetworkReply, and do all these only once it is ready (i.e. when you received the finished signal):

```cpp
if(reply->error()){
    qDebug()<<"error";
}
QByteArray res= reply->readAll();
reply->close();
reply->deleteLater();
// QString str = QString::fromUtf8(res.data(), res.size());
qDebug()<<statusCode;
qDebug()<<res;
```

Probably your problem is that at the moment you call `readAll()`, not the complete response bytes have arrived. Maybe you can check this by stepping in with the debugger, maybe you'll have different timings then, and will get other results.